# trouble with jquery deferreds

Tags: jquery

jQuery's deferred's have never liked me, and I've never been fully able to understand them. I want to be notified when a number of deferreds are ALL done. The real issue is that the number of deferreds won't be the same each time. So I can't do this:

```
$.when(d1, d2, d3).done()
```

I tried `$.when.apply(this, [d1, d2, d3])` but it immediately fires when just one is completed.

Also, I absolutely need a way to pass an array of deferreds. This array is dynamic and will have a different number of deferreds each time my function executes.

I know there is probably an obvious solution, but I am oblivious to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). It clearly says you can pass one or more deferred objects to `$.when`.

On the other hand, if you pass an argument that's not deferred (like an array in your example) the `done` function will fire at once, assuming the argument is a resolved Deferred.

Comment: I know i can pass them, but I have to do so with a pre-decided number of arguments so I can pass them directly. My problem is the deferreds are dynamic and will never have a pre-decided number of arguments. I need someway to pass an array of deferreds.

Comment: Oh, sorry, then just do `$.when.apply($, [YOUR_DEFFERED_OBJECTS_HERE])`

Comment: i was using apply(this) instead of apply($). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UnderscorJS can do what you want, check out this: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#after